# Redirect Readable object stdout process to file in node

Tags: node.js, parsing, stream, markdown

I use an [NPM library](https://github.com/cwjohan/markdown-to-html) to parse markdown to HTML like this:

```js
var Markdown = require('markdown-to-html').Markdown;
var md = new Markdown();

...

md.render('./test', opts, function(err) {
  md.pipe(process.stdout)
});
```

This outputs the result to my terminal as intended.

However, I need the result inside the execution of my node program. I thought about writing the output stream to file and then reading it in at a later time but I can't figure out a way to write the output to a file instead.

I tried to play around `var file = fs.createWriteStream('./test.html');` but the node.js streams rather give me headaches than results.

I've also looked into the library's repo and `Markdown` inherits from Readable via util like this:

```js
var util = require('util');

var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
util.inherits(Markdown, Readable);
```

Any resources or advice would be highly appreciated. (I would also take another library for parsing the markdown, but this gave me the best results so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually creating a writable file-stream and piping the markdown to this stream should work just fine. Try it with:

```
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./output.html');
md.render('./test', opts, function(err) {
  md.pipe(writeStream)
});

// in case of errors you should handle them
writeStream.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```